# How to select an element using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to select my radio button value within multiple divs but i don't know.

Also, append text within table but it doesn't work.  maybe my syntax is wrong?

I've also tried appendTo() but same. nothing appears on the screen

input radio is located..

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="section1">
<table class="question">
<tr><td><input type="radio" value="yes" name="tv"/></td><td><p id="position"></p></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

And below is my jquery source in script.js

```
$('#section1.input:radio["tv"]').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'yes') {
       $('#position').append("test appending");
});
```

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com and http://try.jquery.com.

Comment: dom [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) functions with jquery -try learing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is totally wrong.

- `input` shouldn't be prefixed by a dot, it isn't a CSS class ;
- You need a space between `#section1` and `input`, since the input is a child of your div ;
- You forgot `name=` in the brackets.

Try something like:

```js
$('#section1 input:radio[name="tv"]').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'yes') {
       $('#position').append("test appending");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="section1">
  <table class="question">
   <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" value="yes" name="tv"/></td><td><p id="position"></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [:radio](https://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/)